# strlen & special chars

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having an issue finding a solution here.. I'm developing a WordPress theme for a client that uses a `for()` loop to iterate through the title of the page so it can be wrapped in `<span>`s and displayed vertically.. the loop uses `strlen()` to find the length of the title but since some of the page titles include '...' or commas in the title it returns the html chars instead.. I can't figure out what is causing that and every effort via `htmlspecialchars_decode()` or `html_entity_decode()` doesn't work.. any suggestions? Is there something going on with the for loop that I'm now aware of?

Since it was requested here is the actual code:

```
$p_title = get_the_title($port_page->ID);
   $title = '';

   for($i=0;$i<strlen($p_title);$i++){
   if(($p_title[$i])){
     $title .="<span>$p_title[$i]</span>";
    }
```

I've tried using mb_strlen as well.. the problem with searching for a specific character to replace doesn't necessarily solve the problem since page titles are arbitrarily set by the site owner..

The weird thing is the Title is not encoded in any way and echo's normally before the for loop.. So it's as if something is converting it..

Comment: Can you show what kind of data you are doing a `strlen()` on exactly? Also maybe some code.

Comment: Do you want to decode the HTML entities or remove them from the string? If you want to remove them, you must decode them and, after that, use str_replace to remove them.

Comment: check the functions.php file to see if anything is filtering the get_the_title() function in anyway and converting it?

Comment: Nope nothing converting it that I can see.. I'm using a theme framework that I built and I have no filters in there for that purpose. If I echo out the title before the for loop it displays as it should, only when it is passed through the loop is it converted.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds a lot like a character encoding issue with multibyte characters. Can you try replacing `strlen()` with `mb_strlen()` and see if it does the job?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php

Comment: My issue was that substr() returned a garbage character if the end index was a special character. Thanks @James, this just provoked me to the path to understanding multibyte characters in php.

Answer (score 6):

`strlen()` only returns the number of *bytes* in a string. Some special characters can be represented with multiple bytes, and Unicode can also make single 'characters' like a copyright symbol ("©") occupy many characters (e.g. `&copy;`).

Your "..." (ellipsis) can be a [special character in Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm) for example.

The quick and dirty solution I suggest:

```
// Example string should be 1 character long, 6 bytes
$text = "&copy;";
$bytes = strlen($text);

mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');    
$text = html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");                 
$length = mb_strlen($text);

print "String is ".$length." characters long, ".$bytes." bytes long";
```

Note that I'm assuming your string is already UTF-8. If it isn't, convert it first.